# HttpWebRequest to https server works in fiddler but NOT from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest, fiddler

Here is the scenario. I have written code use a digital certificate to GET cookies from a secured url, to in turn POST data back to another url using the retrieved cookies and same digital certificate. The GET works and cookies are retrieved, the POST comes back with an error 500. I installed fiddler to see what was going on...POST looks fine...cookies are present. I used the feature in fiddler that allows creating a request via drag and drop. POST the exact same POST recorded from C# code that was recorded in fiddler and it works!

What is Fiddler doing that Visual Studio is not? It must be doing something if fiddler can POST the data but Visual Studio returns an error 500. Here is the code below:

```
X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate("mycert.pfx", "certpassword");
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://servertoGETcookies/fileUpload.html");
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
req.Method = "GET";
req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
CookieCollection ck = req.CookieContainer.GetCookies(req.RequestUri);
string strcookie = ck[0].Value;
string strcookie2 = ck[1].Value;
Response.Close();

req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://servertoPOSTdatawithcookies/main");
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
Cookie auth = new Cookie("_wl_authcookie_", strcookie2);
Cookie jsess = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", strcookie);
auth.Domain = "server";
jsess.Domain = "server";
req.CookieContainer.Add(auth);
req.CookieContainer.Add(jsess);
req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
req.Method = "POST";

Byte[] data = ReadByteArrayFromFile("filewithdatatoPOST.txt");
req.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream myStream = req.GetRequestStream();
myStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
myStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse Response2 = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Stream strm = Response2.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(strm);
Response2.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your code work if you set

```
req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
```

on all your WebRequests?

Comment: Thanks but now there's another problem. The post from fiddler responds with expected results (i.e. submitted x). The post from Visual Studio is as if there wasn't a post (i.e. same as if I didn't post anything).

Comment: The text in the file I'm posting is suppose to act as if I pressed a button to upload the file with data: `code`--timestamp Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action" FILEUPLOAD --timestamp Content-Disposition: form-data; name="browseFile";filename="fileuploading.txt" Content-Type: text/plain Meter Daily *** 12345,123,Unit,04/11/2011 1,123.000 2,123.000

Comment: Sorry...tried to mark as useful but I don't have enough of a reputation here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!! It wasn't related to the Expect100Continue.

So after weeks of troubleshooting....6 different programmers....I figured it out. I'm not sure if this is always true, but in this scenario the problem was that the url we were getting cookies from:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://servertoGETcookies/fileUpload.html");
```

was not the same as the url that we were posting the data back to:

```
req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://servertoPOSTdatawithcookies/main");
```

Getting the cookies and posting back to the same url fixed the issue:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://servertoGETandPOSTcookies/main");
req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://servertoGETandPOSTcookies/main");
```